# How to set "Grid Definitions" in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've been using Windows Phone quite a long, and there's something call by `RowDefinition` which is to separate rows by the `Height`, but how to use this on Android? There's my exemple how I'm using Windows Phone

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And then :

```
<Border Grid.Row="0"..../>
```

And that is the [result](http://prntscr.com/apiiyj)

Comment: 404 Not Found. I wish it's there :( You need to add custom drawables backgrounds to your items in the table layout.

Comment: "404 Not Found" what that means? Thanks, i will search about table layout!

Comment: So you want the rows to all be equal height?  Put them all in a vertical linear layout, set the height to 0dp, and set the layout_weight to 1 on all of them

Comment: RowsTable? cu'z i don't know how to use on android!

Answer (score 0):

You can give vertical and Horizontal Spacing to `GridView`.

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvClient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scrollbar"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="defaultPosition"

        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"  

>
```

I hope this will help.